# Local variables out of reach

Tags: linux, perl

I have a Perl script that is supposed to read input from a system command, namely `service $service status` where `$service` points to user input stored in an array structure. It should be possible for the user to check a single service such as **ssh** or several services at once such as **ssh,named,cups** where the services are separated by a comma sign. The program then splits the services into an array and calls the command for each of the user specified services.

My program code looks like this.

```
print "Please provide the service name that you wish to analyze (Named service):\n";

my $service_name_input = <>;
chomp($service_name_input);
my @service_list = split(/,/, $service_name_input);

foreach my $service (@service_list)
{
    open(my $service_input, '-|', "service", $service, "status");
}

while (my $line = <$service_input>)
{
    #Matches for "running".
    if ($line =~ m/(\(running\))/)
    {
        print "The service $service is running.\n";
    }
    #Matches for "dead".
    elsif ($line =~ m/(dead)/)
    {
        print "The service $service is dead.\n";
    }
}
```

The problem here is that the program requires explicit package name for `$service_input` in the while statement, and for `$service` when printing although they are already assigned that. Any guidance towards a solution will be highly appreciated.

Comment: Maybe `while()` should be inside `foreach`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`$service_input` and `$service` are only visible within you `for` loop because you define it there. I think your `while` loop should be moved inside the `for` loop.

You have to change your code to this

```
for my $service ( @service_list ) {

    open( my $service_input, '-|', 'service', $service, 'status' );

    while ( my $line = <$service_input> ) {

        if ( $line =~ /\(running\)/ ) {
            print "The service $service is running.\n";
        }
        elsif ( $line =~ /dead/ ) {
            print "The service $service is dead.\n";
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: You might also want to check against `service` command failing to run (if the user doesn't have necessary permissions, for example): `open … or die "Can't execute service: $!";